# Rid of RxLifeCycle Trello dependency

Tags: android, rx-java2, activity-lifecycle

I'm not an expert on RxJava sorry if my question is a dummy question, I notice that my project is using [RxLifeCycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) dependency, I want to rid of it from the project due to the author [advice](https://blog.danlew.net/2017/08/02/why-not-rxlifecycle/), I wonder how I should remove it, it's just enough to create a composite disposable and dispose all my disposables at onDestroy() method? or is necessary to something else?

Thank you so much.

EDIT:

I provide some examples of the code
First, everything inherits from a base activity, this activity has this method which is used across all activities

```
public <T> Observable<T> bindRxToActivity(Observable<T> observable, boolean isSilent) {
    if (!isSilent) {
        loading(true);
        hideKeyboard();
    }

    return observable
            .compose(bindToLifecycle())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnEach(r -> handleDoOnEach())
            .doOnNext(this::handleDoOnNext);
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
bindRxToActivity(intentApi.evaluation(), false)
            .subscribe(
                    { this.handleTransferEvaluationSuccess(it) },
                    { this.evaluateTransferFailed(it) }
            )
```

In all scenarios of the activities is used as above.

and for fragments:

```
public <T> Observable<T> bindRxToFragment(Observable<T> observable, boolean silent) {
    if (!silent) {
        this.loading(true);
        listener.hideKeyboard();
    }

    return observable
            .compose(bindToLifecycle())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnEach(r -> handleDoOnEach())
            .doOnNext(this::handleDoOnNext);
}
```

And it is used like this in all fragments:

```
baseFragment.bindRxToFragment(baseFragment.r.loginApi().login(login), true)
            .subscribe(
                    login1 -> loginSuccess(BaseActivity, login1, listener),
                    baseFragment::handleError
            );
```

So what could be the best approach to use manual disposing of the observers?

Thanks

Comment: I would say it depends on your use-case. Could you please provide some code samples?

Comment: @HansWurst of course, I've added some examples, thanks!